# matlab plotting a family of functions

Tags: matlab, function, plot

Generate a plot showing the graphs of

```
y=(2*a+1)*exp(-x)-(a+1)*exp(2*x)
```

in the range x ∈ <-2, 4> for all integer values of a between -3 and 3

I know how to make typical plot for 2 values and set a range on the axes, but how to draw the graph dependent on the parameter a?

Comment: Ahh, of course... you'll want to use `bsxfun`.

Comment: I have pdf files about matlab with various tasks and (sometimes) examples, unfortunately to this issue I doesn't have any tips. Further to previous examples it should be really easy, but I think that I overlooked something... It isn't a homework anyway, I'm trying to understand matlab to pass an exam and I base on this files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a simple for loop as follows. You basically loop through each value of `a` and plot the corresponding `y` function.

```
clear
clc
close all

x = -2:4;

%// Define a
a = -3:3;

%// Counter for legend
p = 1;
LegendText = cell(1,numel(a));

figure;
hold on %// Important to keep all the lines on the same plot.

for k = a

    CurrColor = rand(1,3);

    y= (2*k+1).*exp(-x)-(k+1).*exp(2.*x);

    plot(x,y,'Color',CurrColor);

    %// Text for legend
    LegendText{p} = sprintf('a equals %d',k);
    p = p+1;
end
legend(LegendText,'Location','best')
```

Which gives something like this:

[image]

You can customize the graph as you like. Hope that helps get you started!

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on [*Ben Voigt*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032688/matlab-plotting-a-family-of-functions#comment44450480_28032688): A more advanced technique would be to replace the `for`-loop with a call to `bsxfun` to generate a matrix of evaluations of `M(i,j) = f(x(i),a(j))` and call `plot` with this matrix. Matlab will then use the columns of the matrix and plot each column with individual colors.

```
%%// Create a function handle of your function
f = @(x,a) (2*a+1)*exp(-x)-(a+1)*exp(2*x);
%%// Plot the data
x = linspace(-2, 4);
as = -3:3;
plot(x, bsxfun(f,x(:),as));
%%// Add a legend
legendTexts = arrayfun(@(a) sprintf('a == %d', a), as, 'uni', 0);
legend(legendTexts, 'Location', 'best');
```

You could also create the evaluation matrix using `ndgrid`, which explicitly returns all combinations of the values of `x` and `as`. Here you have to pay closer attention on properly vectorizing the code. (We were lucky that the `bsxfun` approach worked without having to change the original `f`.)

```
f = @(x,a) (2*a+1).*exp(-x)-(a+1).*exp(2*x); %// Note the added dots.
[X,As] = ndgrid(x,as);
plot(x, f(X,As))
```

[image: Family of plots]

However for starters, you should get familiar with loops.